# Bluetooth speakers not working

Tags: audio

I am trying to get audio to play through my Bluetooth speakers on a Windows 10 machine.  I am using a USB Bluetooth adapter.
I have downloaded the adapter software, I get the units to pair and connect, under sound it shows up as a Bluetooth headset device, I set as the default. But when I play a song the audio comes out of the computer speakers not the Bluetooth speaker.

What do I need to do in order for the sound to be played through the Bluetooth speakers rather than my Windows 10 computer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the sound preferences (Right click on the sound icon in the task bar then pick the second in the list).

There, you can specify which device should output the computer sound.